# Adding ClassName of td with in the click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have use the following code snippet to create the tr of table in Jquery.

Code snippet:

```
<tr>
        <td class="rowcell">
            <div>
                <div class="intend" style="width: 24px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div>
                <div class="style='float:" left'=""></div>
                <div style="width: 10px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div>
                <div>Task 3</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="rowcell">
            <div>01/01/2013</div>
        </td>
        <td class="rowcell">
            <div>01/05/2013</div>
        </td><td class="rowcell">
            <div>5 days</div>
             </td>
        <td class="rowcell">
            <div>77</div>
        </td>
        </tr>
```

In this case I have invoke the click event for parent of the table. with in the click event I have use the following code snippet to change the className of td to apply the Selection Background, but ClassName cannot change in this case.

Code Snippet

```
//Here $ganttGridRows table rows.
        var $ganttGridRows = $(this.getGanttGridTreeRows());

        //Clicking in the row
        var row = $target.closest('tr');


        var index = $ganttGridRows.index(row);
        var item = this.model.currentViewRange[recordIndex];
        this.model.selectedRow = this.model.ganttRecords.indexOf(item);
        var args = {};
        if (this.model.selectedRow != -1)
            args = { currentRowIndex: this.model.selectedRow, currrentRow: $ganttGridRows.eq(this.model.selectedRow), currentData: this.model.ganttRecords[this.model.selectedRow] };
        if (this._trigger("rowSelecting", args))
            return;
        this.cleanUpSelection();
        this._selectedRowsIndexes = [];
        var cell = $target.closest('td');
        //Here index is the rowindex of the selected row
        $($ganttGridRows[index]).find('.rowcell').addClass("selectionbackground");
```

But in this did not working while using div with in the td. But if I use without div in td and directly assign the text like below code snippet and it is working fine for me.

Code Snippet

```
<tr>
         <td class="rowcell">Task 1</td>
        <td class="rowcell">01/01/2013</td>
        <td class="rowcell">01/05/2013</td>
        <td class="rowcell">5 days</td>
        <td class="rowcell">31</td>
        </tr>
```

Can you pleases any look in to this and provide suggestion to resolve this problem and , explain what is the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: could u set up a fiddle and share the link??

Comment: can you please show all of the html and javascript because it is very hard to see where the error is coming from

Comment: Thank you for your help , finally i have found the mistake in my code and resolve the problem.